# Python - using a collections items in expected results pytest

Tags: python, pytest

I have a somewhat simple code:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize( "my_input_list, expected" , [
   ( .... , {( 11111 ) : [ (1, 'A1') ] } ) ] )

def test_1( my_input_list, expected ) :
    ..... function_result = foo()
    assert function_result == expected
```

so when running `pytest -v` it fails with :

```
E         Full diff:
E         - defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {(11111,): [(1, 'A1')]})
E         + {11111: [(1, 'A1')]}
```

which is expected since `foo() returns a defaultdict`. But how do I pass that in the expected arg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize( "my_input_list, expected" , [
   ( .... , { (11111,)  : [ (1, 'A1') ] } ) ] )

def test_1( my_input_list, expected ) :
    ..... function_result = foo()
    assert function_result == expected
```